# What is meant by "Die Me, Dichotomy"?

Tags: farscape

The season 2 finale episode of ***Farscape*** is called "Die Me, Dichotomy".

This alone among all season finale titles seems inexplicable to me.

- Season 1 finale: "Family Ties" references John and Zhaan's conversation in which they agree that they are family - it's also a 1980s sitcom.
- **Season 2 finale: "Die Me, Dichotomy" - not sure what this means and the word "Dichotomy" doesn't appear anywhere in the episode**
- Season 3 finale: "Dog With Two Bones" - John utters this exact phrase in a conversation with Noranti - his desire to be with Aeryn and his desire to get back to Earth are the two "bones" in question
- Season 4 finale: "Bad Timing" - references Aeryn's line in the end of the episode "You and your timing" which she says due to the fact that John proposed to Aeryn shortly before being blown into a million pieces (also is apparently a meta-reference to the fact that the show was cancelled after setting up a massive cliffhanger)

While most Farscape episode titles are funny and a play on words in some way, the season 2 finale title seems totally random and I can't understand the relevance of it. However, Farscape is also known for pop culture references, so maybe this is something I missed.

Does anyone know what "Die Me, Dichotomy" could have reference to and/or how it relates to the events of the episode?

Comment: Confused as to what being a 1980s sitcom has to do with anything. Since you're looking for relevance.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Most Farscape episode titles are both relevant AND a pop culture reference of some kind

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a play on John's dichotomy: his mental split between his native self and the Scorpius implant. The John side is trying to surgically remove - kill - the Scorpius side. The Scorpius side is trying to take over and suppress - kill - the John side.

Comment: Hmm, but still why "Die Me, Dichotomy" and not "Kill Me, Dichotomy" or something else even more normal (/grammatically correct)? It seems that this title was deliberately crafted to be a sort of pun or pop culture reference, but I don't get it.

Comment: Speak it out loud. Die Me are the first and last syllables of Dichotomy. It's meant to be poetic, I think.

Comment: Ahh!! I get it. I never realised that before.

Comment: Also, each half is fighting the other, telling it to die. It's meant to come from John/Scorpius.